# Do we need separate tags for [vnc]? They are oddly tagged

Tags: discussion, retagging

We seem to have [vnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vnc), [vncserver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vncserver) and [vnc-viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vnc-viewer).

(Please note that I have retagged a small number [vnc-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vnc-server) --> [vncserver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vncserver) as per Ask a SU mod room)

Some questions are tagged with all three, which seems pretty weird given that we have [vnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vnc).

How should we retag them?

Comment: 0 questions tagged `vnc-client`.

Comment: notice also [VNC-Viewer]. Would this site cover a teacher with 12 VNC clients logged into it? http://superuser.com/questions/385545/can-vnc-server-be-put-into-a-read-only-mode Where the only existing problem would be the clients ? Mabey.   Did a single question in the lists in thier need to find a tag Need [server] or [client] seperation tags? I dont think so.   Thier questions would have been better tagged with What VNC (real, tight, ultra, etc), and on What OS.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I meant [tag:vnc-viewer], my bad.

Comment: @Psycogeek Wouldn't the combination of `[real]`, `[tight]` or `[ultra]` and `[vnc]` be sufficient to specify *which program* the user has?

Comment: @DanielBeck lol, dont ask :-)  I think in this situation, the programs are single words RealVNC , TightVNC , Photoshop, and From the use of them in some threads , I am not sure if VNCviewer or VNCserver are not some kind of program.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android A RealVNC application for android is named "VNCviewer"

Answer (score 3):

Why not just have the vnc tag only, and then you figure out if there is a problem in the server or the client from just reading the question.

I doubt that there are many SU users that are experts in ONLY vnc-clients so I don't foresee loosing any value by dropping the other two tags.

Answer (score 3):

[vncserver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vncserver) and [vnc-viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vnc-viewer) should be removed (and replaced with [vnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vnc) where necessary).

More product-specific tags should be applied where it makes sense, like

- [realvnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/realvnc)
- [tightvnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tightvnc)
- [ultravnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ultravnc)
- [chickenvnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chickenvnc)

These are all perfectly fine for me but I would use them in addition to [vnc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vnc).

Answer (score 1):

formatted comment.

VNC - arbitrary term for all VNCs

- RealVNC - Branded VNC type
- TightVNC
- UltraVNC
- ChickenVNC
- JollyfastVNC
- FreeNX
- Xpra
- xrdp
- WindowsRemote
- vine
- Tiger
- KDE
- ARD
- Mocha
- etc
- - VNCclient - executable name of branded type
    VNCviewer
    VNCserver

VNC-server - The server itself of a VNC connection
VNC-Client - The client in a VNC connection.

It is something like this? with other brands, and executables names.
trying to form a pattern here that is repeated elsewhere.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Are you simply listing various types of VNC software? Are you suggesting tags?

Comment: it is a comment only. Please do anything you want with it, edit stuff in or out, or whatever helps. I am trying to form the picture, the hierarcy somehow.

Comment: I am comming up with brands alone being a very large number , Brands being important because they have different features and configurations. Thier executable names can be repeated across brands and OS. Trying to put every executable of anything in would be rediculous.  So I see the line being drawn at VNC only or  "identifying the VNC type by brand". and dumping everything below it.

Comment: Follow: [VNC] is too arbitrary to follow or find specifics to get help with one program. I (myself) would never attempt to follow it.  So following [RealVnc] or [TightVNC] or your favorite Mac VNC would be possible.  Find: [VNC][OSname] is not too bad, [UltraVNC][OSname] better if they had named the os more often.

Comment: I guess this raises the question:  Are tags supposed to be super-precise (which could lead to tag quantity bloat) or more broad "region of difficulty" categories, with the actual question stating with specificity what the precise "atomic" elements of the problem are?